# Appending an Array and Printing php

Tags: php, arrays, string, printing, append

This code wont work can anybody create a solution?

```
<?php
  //Assigns 10 to test1. 20 to test2. 30 to test3.
  $array1 = array(10 => "test1", 20 => "test2", 30 => "test3");  
  //Creates a blank array.
  $blank = new ArrayObject(array()); 

  $blank->append(array("20")); //Adds the value 20, to the blank array.
  $blank->append(array("30")); //Adds the value 30, to the blank array.

  print($array1[$blank[0]]); // should print "test2"
  print($array1[$blank[1]]); // should print "test3"
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for:

```
<?php
  //Assigns 10 to test1. 20 to test2. 30 to test3.
  $array1 = array(10 => "test1", 20 => "test2", 30 => "test3");  
  //Creates a blank array.
  $blank = new ArrayObject();

  $blank->append(array("20")); //Adds the value 20, to the blank array.
  $blank->append(array("30")); //Adds the value 30, to the blank array.

  print($array1[$blank[0][0]]); // should print "test2"
  print($array1[$blank[1][0]]); // should print "test3"
?>
```

Here, `$blank` would be multidimensional.

See http://ideone.com/XsgnSz

Or perhaps more likely:

```
<?php
  //Assigns 10 to test1. 20 to test2. 30 to test3.
  $array1 = array(10 => "test1", 20 => "test2", 30 => "test3");  
  //Creates a blank array.
  $blank = new ArrayObject();

  $blank->append("20"); //Adds the value 20, to the blank array.
  $blank->append("30"); //Adds the value 30, to the blank array.

  print($array1[$blank[0]]); // should print "test2"
  print($array1[$blank[1]]); // should print "test3"
?>
```

See http://ideone.com/eyXL6v

Comment: Thanks for the response but this gives me the error: Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Comment: @user1933466 It works in both of the ideone links in my answer.